# How to fix strange problem with Zabbix (strange alphabets on every graph)?

Tags: zabbix

I have strange alphabets on every graph.
Anybody know how to fix it?
[image: x]

Answer (score 0):

Had reinstall zabbix frontend and problem has gone.